# Dataframe Transpose and Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe (df) like this.

```
Color  20-05-2020  21-05-2020  22-05-2020  23-05-2020
Yellow   10           20          30          40
Red      15           25          35          45
Blue     23           34          45          56
```

When I transposed using `df.T`, I got like this.

```
Color        Yellow  Red  Blue
20-05-2020     10    15    23
21-05-2020     20    25    34
22-05-2020     30    35    45
23-05-2020     40    45    56
```

When I checked `df.index`, I found,

```
Index(['Color', '20-05-2020', '21-05-2020', '22-05-2020', '23-05-2020'], dtype='object', length=...)
```

How do I remove "Color" from index? Also I want to name the index as "Date". How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.index.name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.name.html):

```
>>> df
        20-05-2020  21-05-2020  22-05-2020  23-05-2020
Color                                                 
Yellow          10          20          30          40
Red             15          25          35          45
Blue            23          34          45          56

>>> df = df.T
>>> df.columns.name = ''
>>> df.index.name = 'Date'
>>> df
             Yellow  Red  Blue
Date         
20-05-2020     10    15    23
21-05-2020     20    25    34
22-05-2020     30    35    45
23-05-2020     40    45    56
```

Or,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T, 
                      index=df.columns.rename('Date'),
                      columns=df.index.rename(''))
>>> df
             Yellow  Red  Blue
Date         
20-05-2020     10    15    23
21-05-2020     20    25    34
22-05-2020     30    35    45
23-05-2020     40    45    56
```

Or you can use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
>>> df.reindex(df.index.rename('')).T.reindex(df.columns.rename('Date'))
            Yellow  Red  Blue
Date                         
20-05-2020      10   15    23
21-05-2020      20   25    34
22-05-2020      30   35    45
23-05-2020      40   45    56
```

Depending on your preference, you can either set `df.columns.name='Date'` or `df.index.name='Date'`.

Comment: I tried all 3 methods. But It's still there. Only change I notice, when I do `df.index` after any of the methods, I find `name='Date'` is there.

Comment: My answer is based on the assumption that the `name` of your `index` is `Color`. If that is not the case. Try the following: `df.columns.name = '';df.index.name = 'Date';df = df.T`

Comment: Now `df.index` is like this.
`Index(['', '20-05-2020', '21-05-2020', '22-05-2020', '23-05-2020'], dtype='object', length=)`. How to remove the first blank?